# /proc consuming space on hard disk gradually

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, centos7, diskspace

EC2 instance running centos 7.0 hard disk space is consumed slowly, which is flushed after reboot.

Content :  Base OS,  Cloudwatch Agent, CodeDeploy agent, nginx, Anti Virus MacFee,  Java application (log file is under control).

**Screen shot 1 before reboo**t :  Disk space utilized **75%**

As per this screenshot we are finding top 10 most space consuming files  and /proc is on top.

### [image: Screen shot 1 before reboot]

**Screen shot 2 After reboot** :  Disk space utilized **9%**

used files are flushed, not able to identify if the issue is caused by application or other components.

---

[image]

Comment: do not see how this is related to java, but anyway, from root directory periodically do a `du -hs *` and compare the output

Comment: You have to read the output carefully. `/proc` is not on top of the output of `du` because it's taking up disk space - it's just the `du` tool warning you that it cannot read certain things in the `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

procfs is a virtual filesystem, it's technically impossible to take up your disk space. You can read more about it [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).

You can confirm this by running `df -ah`.